# How to parse this time format in Obj-C using NSDateFormatter?

Tags: iphone, date, timezone, nsdateformatter

I am having a lot of trouble trying to parse the following timestamp using NSDateFormatter:

```
30 MAR 2011 11:10:59 HKT
```

I could parse everything except for the timezone "HKT" at the end. I have tried using multiple timezone ID strings without any luck (they always return nil as soon as I try to parse the time zone using any timezone character). What could be the problem?

This doesn't work - **z~zzz: (Specific GMT Timezone Abbreviation)**:

```
[oDateParser setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
```

nor does this - **v~vvv: (General GMT Timezone Abbreviation)**:

```
[oDateParser setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss vvv"];
```

Comment: I suspect you'll have to strip off the timezone ID and handle that separately.

Comment: (The problem is that timezone abbreviations are not standardized, and the formatter likely only recognizes a few.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this can save you a lot of work and time http://www.stepcase.com/blog/2008/12/02/format-string-for-the-iphone-nsdateformatter/ Cheers :)

Comment: I got those strings from the above link, no dice.

Answer (score 0):

The format should be:

```
[oDateParser setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
```

(note the capital ZZZ for timezone)